# What is the syntactic category of 'there are'?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I have a background in philosophy and logic, and I don't know much about syntax. I guess 'there are' is not a determiner. I would simply call 'there are' a quantifier, and something like 'there are Fs' a quantifier phrase, but I want to know the name they receive in the literature on Syntax.

Comment: You guess right; it is not a determiner, not even a constituent. The "there" that occurs in examples like _There are two doctors present_ is a noun phrase comprising a meaningless dummy pronoun (a subclass of noun) functioning as subject of the sentence. "Are" is the verb, the head of the predicate verb phrase _are two doctors present_. "There" when used this way is sometimes called 'existential there' since it derives its name from the fact that one of its uses is to express propositions concerning existence.

Answer (score 2):

You're right -- "there are" is not a determiner. In, e.g., "There are two snails here." "there" is a noun phrase subject and "are" is a finite auxiliary verb. The term 'quantifier' is sometimes used for "two", "some", and other words that concern quantity.

I don't see a lot of difference between the terminologies of logic and linguistics, but in the example you've chosen, the meaning is expressed in a different way.  In translating back and forth from predicate logic to English, we have to change between a noun phrase "there" in English and a quantifier "there (is)" in logic, but that doesn't make the two the same, of course.  They correspond.

Comment: So, in 'there are cats on the mat', 'there are' is a noun phrase and 'there are cats' is also a noun phrase? Or 'there are' is just not a syntactic unit?

Comment: No, it is just the "there" that is a noun phrase.  I don't think "there are" is a syntactic unit.

Comment: 'There' is the subject noun (which is sort of a dummy), 'are' is the verb, 'cats' is the complement, and 'on' is the preposition in an adverbial phrase.  The logical meaning is 'some cats exist on the mat'.

Comment: @AmI, I do not agree that "there" is a noun -- it is a noun phrase.  Nouns can take preceding articles and can be modified by adjectives or relative clauses.  Usually, they have plurals in -s.  "There" has none of these properties.

Comment: You're both right. It's a dummy and has no property except preverbal existence as subject. Hence it's an automatic NP, without any N or N', the same way _nobody_ is automatically singular instead of plural, even though 0 isn't 1.

Comment: Not every "there" is a subject. "I hate for there to be cats." "I believe there to be cats."

Comment: Downstairs 1 -> upstairs 2? _For_ marking infinitive subjects?

Comment: @JohnLawler, No.  Obviously the infinitive is derived from a sentence with "there" as subject, but that doesn't make "there" the subject of an infinitive (if there even is such a thing as subject of infinitive).

Comment: I'm a nominalist, sorry. What it would be called were it not in an infinitive clause but rather a tensed clause is what I would be happy calling it in an infinitive clause too.

Comment: @JohnLawler, So nominalists believe that anything derived from a subject must be one?  Wasn't it Parmenides who believed that nothing changes?  (For me, the S2, with grammatical relation 2, of an infinitive, cannot contain anything less oblique, including subject, finite auxiliary, performative adverb, and so on.)

Comment: Nope, nominalists believe that names are not essences, but merely convenient labels.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that this can be analyzed as a **locative inversion** construction, where the order of subject and verb's complement (usually a adverb with locative meaning) can be inverted.

For example, you can say *the rain falls down* (non-inverted form) or *down falls the rain* (inverted form).

You would then analyze a sentence like *There are three dogs on the grass* by considering the non-inverted homologue *Three dogs are there in the grass*. As with other syntactic alternations in English, the constituents keep the same lexical categories (noun phrase and adverbial phrase), and the same semantic roles (copula subject is *three dogs* and copula complement is *there in the grass*), but the arguments have "demoted" syntactic roles: the subject in the non-inverted version becomes the complement in the inverted version, while the locative complement becomes the adjunct in the inverted version. The only difference in meaning is that *there* is bleached of its deictic meaning in the inverted version.

So the adverb "there" has no semantic role, it is an adverb, and the subject of the sentence. Subjects with no semantic role are called *expletive subjects*, so that is the most informative label you could give "there" when discussing its grammatical role. Adverbs normally cannot be the subject of a sentence (one exception being the locative inversion construction), so that's why it's important to note that this is a locative inversion construction.